# Where are the reference manuals for Excel 2008?

Tags: ms-office

I have a 2008 copy of Excel that I use to proof the occasional Excel file I need to email.  When I click on the help menu item I am directed to a Microsoft advertisement.  Where are the help files or manuals?

Comment: Is this Excel for Windows or Mac?

Comment: tbh, in 08 they probably came on CD

Comment: It's a Mac and I have no idea about a CD.   Maybe I need to go buy the new version.  I was hoping there would be a a Microsoft webpage with the documentation.  I would export from Numbers, but dates are getting messed up.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the What's New page for Excel: https://support.office.com/en-us/excel.  You'll find Mac toward the bottom.  Once you're at the SOC site you can search for specific questions, like "format dates".

Comment: The support.office.com site does not seem to cover Office 2008.